# Show that $\{ a_n \}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Define $\{a_n\}$ by $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2a_n}$

Pf

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then $\exists n(\epsilon)$ s.t. if $n> n(\epsilon)$ then $\forall n > n(\epsilon) $

Then,$ |a_n -2|< \epsilon$, since $1 < a_n < 2$, then, $1 < a_k < 2, \forall k > n(\epsilon)$

Then $1 < \sqrt{2a_k} = a_{k+1} <$ $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}$,  so $1<a_n< 2  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Prove that $a_n$ is increasing. This can be done by using $a_n < 2$, which you already proved.

Comment: No proof here so far, except, perhaps, that every term of the sequence is between 1 and 2.